# Is assigning a type to an enum standard C?

Tags: c, types, enums, enumeration, portability

I have seen `enum` declarations like this:

```
enum ProgrammingLanguage: unsigned char {
    C = 0,
    CPlusPlus,
    Rust,
    Java,
    Javascript,
    Python
};
```

This only allocates one byte for this type. My question is, is this standard C or a GCC extension? Do I need to worry about portability if I decide to do this?

Comment: This is not in Standard C.  It is a C++ feature

Comment: @M.M Are you sure? That would be a shame.

Comment: It's not accepted by any gcc version I tried

Comment: @M.M Then it is a macOS feature. Compiling it in Xcode in a C file works.

Comment: I guess you are actually using clang  (try `gcc -v`). Some macos developer had the brilliant idea of aliasing gcc to clang

Comment: As mentioned in [the answer by KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62443142/440558) it's a Clang-specific extension. As such it's non-portable and should not really be used (IMO).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What is the correct way (in ISO-compliant portable C18) to define a C enumeration with a specific underlying type?

Comment: @Dai There is none. At least if you want to use a "proper" enumeration (i.e. `enum`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is this standard C

No, this is not a part of C language.

> a GCC extension?

No, this is not a GCC extension in C language.

> Do I need to worry about portability if I decide to do this?

You need to worry about compiling such code at all with any C compiler.

This is solely C++ feature.

> Then it is a macOS feature. Compiling it in Xcode in a C file works

It is a [clang extension](https://reviews.llvm.org/D52339).

Answer (score 1):

Appendix A 6.7.2.2 defines an enum as:

```
(6.7.2.2) enum-specifier:
  enum identifier-opt { enumerator-list }
  enum identifier-opt { enumerator-list,}
  enum identifier
```

Comment: Hmmm. The final answer "yes" or "no" would depend on the definition of `identifier-opt`, correct?